# How to make current configuration dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project that i am working on and need to change some things in it. Unfortunately i am not very educated in the javascript world. Right now this works the way it is but is not desirable. I someone could point me in the right direction on what i need to do to get this changed it would be greatly appreciated.

In this section of the function we are assigning the location and page to load when the page comes up. I would like for this to be dynamic, I do not want the location to be hard coded. I have several folders with files in the HMIBuilder Directory.

```
HMI.Builder.init('Files/HMIBuilder/Default/index.html', function () {
  //run code after page/iframe is loaded
});
```

In this part it loads pages in a tree of what is in the direcotry. But only shows the files listed. I would like for this to play with the code above and load the pages that correspond with the current directory. Otherwise the tree shows all the files no matter what directory they are in.

```
HMI.FileManager.addPages(
  [
    { name: "Default", title: "Starter Page", url: "Files/HMIBuilder/Default/index.html", assets: ['Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css', 'Content/themes/redmond/theme.css'] },
    { name: "Tags", title: "Tags", url: "Files/HMIBuilder/Default/Tags.html", assets: ['Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css', 'Content/themes/redmond/theme.css'] },
    { name: "Alarms", title: "Alarms", url: "Files/HMIBuilder/Default/Alarms.html", assets: ['Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css', 'Content/themes/redmond/theme.css'] },
  ]
);
```

Hoping someone can help me out with this. If you need any other information on this just let me know. This project is pretty much all javascript..

thanks in advance!

EDIT --

I will add also, that the only files that need loaded are HTML. They are the files that are being edited. It does not have to display any other file types..

Also the project itself is done in C# MVC so the actions that take place do not necessarily have to be in Javascript, however since this section is pretty much all javascript i felt it was a good place to start.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamic"? Auto-Load the files? Relative paths?

Comment: It sounds like you would like for the code that is loaded in the browser to reflect information about the filesystem it is being served from?  Is that accurate?

Comment: To answer both questions i have another section that shows the folder section and files just not in this section, where having that would be nice but i think a nightmare in rewriting the existing code. This was a solution that was already done that i am trying to make it work for what i have. By dynamic i mean selecting a folder before entering this page so that it loads the index.html into the Iframe. It is an editor. The tree in the editor does not show folders it only shows files and only files that you specify to load..